# Commas, subject and verb

Tags: verbs, oxford-comma

In my understanding, the use of a comma is needed when you are connecting two sentences, which both need there own subject and verb. With that said, in the sentence below:

"The best mindset is to assume she's attracted to you, and that she does not play games"

Is the use of the comma correct? I am questioning this, because the use of the two words "and that" would be my connector instead of just "and". Should the sentence be rewritten to take away the "that"?

"The best mindset is to assume she's attracted to you, and she does not play games"

Comment: Commas are more art than science. In neither of your examples do I find the commas out of place. But you are missing a copula before *attracted*.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the sentences. I was trying to get to it before anyone noticed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the traditional rule, you don't use a comma between parts of a sentence that could not stand alone, parts that take some elliptical words from the rest of the sentence. In both of your examples, the part after the comma is elliptical. However, those who follow that rule are usually not against introducing some extra comma's to aid the reader, or to indicate an afterthought or some other bit that is more loosely connected to the rest of the sentence. So I would say the comma's in your examples are optional.

However, it doesn't work the other way around: if the *and...* part is not elliptical, then you must write a comma. That is not optional, if you follow this rule.

Not also that your last example is ambiguous with the comma. Which does it mean?

> 1. The best mindset is to assume [that] she's attracted to you, and [to assume that] she does not play games.
> 2. The best mindset is to assume she's attracted to you. Oh, and she does not play games.

For that reason, I would avoid the comma in that sentence if it isn't strictly needed (which I think it is not: you most probably intended the elliptical construction as in (1). So I would write it thus:

> The best mindset is to assume she's attracted to you **and** does not play games.

Or thus:

> The best mindset is to assume **that** she's attracted to you **and that** she does not play games.